# How to avoid submitting dask tasks-within-tasks to main scheduler

Tags: dask, dask-distributed

The [task launch](https://distributed.dask.org/en/latest/task-launch.html) documentation shows that the default behavior of `dask.compute` within a dask worker is to launch tasks on the main scheduler.

My desire is NOT to launch on the main scheduler.  My task is doing two steps: using a non-python binary to process 0.1-1.0 TB of data copied onto the local disk, then using dask to convert and write the data out to a zarr store. The binary is multi-threaded, and I'd also like to using a dask locally in multi-process or multi-threaded local way.

For this worker, I use a multi-core machine, but reserve only one thread for dask worker.  I believe this means my task can use all the cores on the machine for both of the above steps.

Is this a viable model, and how would I call `compute` (`distributed.Client().compute` does not seem to work)?  Are there other approaches where I can run my binary exclusively on the machine, and run my parallel zarr write via tasks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When calling dask.compute you can specify a scheduler= option like the following:

```
dask.compute(x, y, scheduler="processes")
```

See https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/scheduling.html for more information